# How to join on a list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Say I have these two dataframes:

```
df1:

ID    Strings
1     'hello, how are you?'
2     'I like the red one.'
3     'You? I think so.'
```

```
df2:

range      Strings
[1]        'hello, how are you?'
[2,3]      'I like the red one. You? I think so.'
```

My aim is to take the sentences in df1 and group them so that they match df2. To do this I have managed to work out a way of labelling the groups I wish them to be in, so in this example, 1 is on its own, but sentence 2 and 3 need to be combined.

Can I do this with a join?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your joins in a list, you could do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['hello, how are you?','I like the red one.', 'You? I think so.'], columns=['sentence'])
 
# rows 1 and 2 are to be merged
join = [[0], [1,2]]

# check if the indexes are in the list items
df['joincol'] = pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda x: [x in j for j in join]).astype(str)

df

sentence    joincol
0   hello, how are you? [True, False] # this is your grouping column
1   I like the red one. [False, True]
2   You? I think so.    [False, True]


# group by and keep uniques
df.groupby('joincol')['sentence'].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).drop_duplicates()

# result

0                     hello, how are you?
1    I like the red one. You? I think so.
Name: sentence, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an intermediate step, and create a `group` column to join on.

Let's make use of `explode` and `pd.merge`:

```
s = df2['range'].explode().reset_index().rename(columns={'index' : 'grp'})

df1a = pd.merge(df1,s,left_on=['ID'],
                right_on=['range'],
                how='left')\
       .groupby('grp')['Strings'].agg(' '.join).to_frame('strings')
```

---

Then you can simply join on the indexes:

```
final = pd.merge(df2,df1a,left_index=True,right_index=True)

print(final)
```

[image]

---

```
print(s)
  grp range
0    0     1
1    1     2
2    1     3
```

---

```
print(df1a)

                                      strings
grp                                          
0                       'hello, how are you?'
1    'I like the red one.' 'You? I think so.'
```